# Custom converter for openCSV

Tags: java, opencsv

I have a CSV that is composed of a fixed part, where each column corresponds to an exact field of the target DTO, and a variable part composed of pairs of values that are to be conveyed into a list of properties like objects.

A line from the input CSV looks like this:

> test1;description test
> 1;to;place1;;;;placeTest;objectType;47.222;;;47.442;;;property1;property
> value 1;property2;property value 2;property3;property value 3

where from "property1" on there is the variable part of the line, which could also not be present.

The header:

> name;description;tenant;road name;direction name;section name;lane
> name;infrastructure
> name;systemTagName;pkStart;latitudeStart;longitudeStart;pkStop;latitudeStop;longitudeStop;properties

The last column "properties" covers under itself the variable part of the line. This header field is the product of a union cells from an Excel file.

This is a portion of the dto:

```
    ...
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 12, required = true)
    private Double localizationStop;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 13, required = false)
    private Double latitudeStop;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 14, required = false)
    private Double longitudeStop;

    @CsvCustomBindByName(column = "properties", converter = ContainerPropertiesConverter.class)
    private List<ContainerProperty> properties;
```

I tried the annotation *CsvCustomBindByName*, believing that would pass all the remaining feilds of the line to my converter, but that does not happen. The converter is never called.

What type of annotation can I use or how can I easily manage the variable portion of the line with openCSV?

Comment: *@CsvCustomBindByName(column = "properties" ...* But there *isn't* a column called properties..?

Comment: The problem is that: "properties" as column name would cover a variable number of pairs of columns below itself. I don't know how to correctly annotate that field or how I can handle it with openCSV

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer since I don't know the API well enough. I would probably work along the lines of adding columns 15-n to a `Map`, treating the mapping positionally

Comment: This CSV comes out of an Excel file, where "properties" is a union-cell of multiple columns, so I'm wandering if only from column 15 I can use a custom mapper. I'll give a try to the map and see if the output is easily usable to build my list of properties

Comment: One problem is that your portrayal of your input file is confusing. Better, clearer data would help

Answer (score 0):

To handle the variable portion of the CSV line with OpenCSV, you can use a custom converter. This converter will be responsible for parsing the variable part of the line and converting it into a list of ContainerProperty objects.

To create a custom converter, you need to implement the CsvConverter interface. This interface has a single method, convert(), which takes a String as input and returns an Object.

In the convert() method, you will need to parse the variable part of the CSV line and convert it into a list of ContainerProperty objects. You can do this by splitting the variable part of the line into pairs of values, and then creating a ContainerProperty object for each pair of values.

Once you have created a custom converter, you need to register it with OpenCSV. You can do this by using the CSVParserBuilder.withConverter() method.

Finally, you need to use the CsvCustomBindByName annotation to bind the variable part of the CSV line to the properties field of your DTO.

Here is an example of a custom converter for parsing the variable part of the CSV line:

```java
public class ContainerPropertiesConverter implements CsvConverter {

    @Override
    public Object convert(String value) {
        List<ContainerProperty> properties = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] pairs = value.split(";;");
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            String[] keyValue = pair.split(";");
            String key = keyValue[0];
            String value = keyValue[1];

            ContainerProperty property = new ContainerProperty();
            property.setKey(key);
            property.setValue(value);

            properties.add(property);
        }

        return properties;
    }
}
```

To register the custom converter with OpenCSV:

```java
CSVParserBuilder builder = new CSVParserBuilder();
builder.withConverter(new ContainerPropertiesConverter());

CSVParser parser = builder.build();
```

example of how to use the CsvCustomBindByName annotation to bind the variable part of the CSV line to the properties field of your DTO:

```java
public class MyDTO {

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 12, required = true)
    private Double localizationStop;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 13, required = false)
    private Double latitudeStop;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 14, required = false)
    private Double longitudeStop;

    @CsvCustomBindByName(column = "properties", converter = ContainerPropertiesConverter.class)
    private List<ContainerProperty> properties;
}
```

Comment: Creating a converter that implements CsvConverter, needs a lot of methods implementation and there is not "convert" method, but "convertToRead". I tried using AbstractBeanField instead, but during the csv file parsing my converter is never called.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy